# Why am I allowed to initialize object of class Test by assigning integer constant in C++?

Tags: c++

Here is my C++ code

```
#include<iostream>

class Test{
        int i;
public:
        Test() { }
        Test(int i){ 
                std::cout << "Constructor called" << std::endl;
                this->i = i;
        }
        void print(){
                std::cout << i << std::endl;
        }
};

int main(){
        Test t = 3;
        t.print();
        return 0;
}
```

I was amused when `Test t = 3;` worked. I do not understand why it is not giving compilation error.

I was under the impression that object of class `Test` should be created in one of the following ways. Are there other ways of creating object of class `Test` which are not covered in following list?

```
Test t1;
Test t2(2);
Test t3 = Test(3);
Test t4(t3);
Test t5 = Test(t4);
Test t6{2};
Test t7 = Test{3};
Test t8{t3};
Test t9 = Test{t4};
Test t10 = {10};
```

Comment: Because there is a constructor `Test(int)`.

Comment: I understand that constructor is being called here. But I was scanning through the C++ standard and did not find any mention of this being allowed. It would be very helpful if you can point out something in the standard which allows this. Thanks!

Comment: If you wanted to disallow that implicit construction you can do `explicit Test(int i)`.  Some C++ guides recommend putting `explicit` on all your constructors except for those that the implicit construction is desired.

Comment: How? There's a section [conversion by constructor](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.conv.ctor). (I wonder why in the example there `f` takes `arg` as argument, it's unused)

Comment: @Eljay this guideline normally don’t require `explicit`  on all constructors, but only on those that require only one argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This syntax:

```
Test t = 3;
```

is a form of [copy-initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization). The effect of this is that the best user-defined-conversion-sequence is selected to initialize `t`. In this particular case, you have provided a conversion constructor `Test(int)` which is the best match and gets called.